# ¿ Como mando para enfrente el menú y la imagen?

Tags: html5

Tengo el siguiente código y estoy intentado mandarlo para enfrente con un `z-index` dandole -1 pero me lo sigue manteniendo atrás. ¿Alguien sabe cual es el error que tengo ?
Ya estuve buscando e intentando. Mi código actual:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="wide wow-animation" lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Site Title-->
  <title>Fresh Farms</title>
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- Stylesheets-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash%7COpen+Sans:300,500,400,400italic,700,600,600italic%7CRaleway%7CLato:400,700%7CRoboto:400">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <div style="background: #212121; padding: 10px 0; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3); clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative; z-index:1;"><a href="https://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/"><img src="images/ie8-panel/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today."></a></div>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!-- <script src="/cdn-cgi/apps/head/3ts2ksMwXvKRuG480KNifJ2_JNM.js"></script> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos-menu.css">
  <style>
    
    ·#logo{
      display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <!-- Page-->
  <div class="page text-center text-md-left">

  
        <!-- Page Heade

 <header>
     
     <nav>
       
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT </a></li>
<center>
<img id="logo" style="padding:0;padding-buttom:13px;margin:0;width:8%; height:8%;" src="images/FreshFarms.png">
</center>
     </nav>



  </header>
  <br>
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video id="video" autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="1_1.mp4" type=video/mp4>
    </video>
</div>
    r-->
    <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video id="video" autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="1_1.mp4" type=video/mp4>
    </video>
 <!-- Page Header-->
    <!-- RD Navbar-->
        
                        <div class="rd-navbar-brand"><a class="brand-name" href="index.html"><img src="images/FreshFarms.png" width="150" alt="Logo Fresh Farms"></a></div>


    <header>
     
     <nav>
       
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT </a></li>
     </nav>



  </header>      </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: podrías agregar el `css` para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Cuanto más alto el valor del `z-index` más arriba en la pila de los elementos, por defecto es 0 así que -1 lo mandará al fondo. También hay que tener en cuenta que `z-index` solo funciona con elementos posicionados y la comparación de nivel es entre elementos hermanos. ¿De todas formas qué es lo que quieres que esté delante?

Answer (score 2):

Buenas amigo espero esto sea lo que buscas

Para superponer un objeto con `z-index` sobre todos los demás puedes usar la propiedad `position:fixed` y un `z-index` superior a los demás otra opción es usar `position:absolute` espero te ayude saludos.

PD: el logo y el video son solo de prueba.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(98, 173, 190, 0.52)
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}

.rd-navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  //background: rgb(150, 250, 216);
  color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="wide wow-animation" lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Site Title-->
  <title>Fresh Farms</title>
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- Stylesheets-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash%7COpen+Sans:300,500,400,400italic,700,600,600italic%7CRaleway%7CLato:400,700%7CRoboto:400">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <div style="background: #212121; padding: 10px 0; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3); clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative; z-index:1;"><a href="https://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/"><img src="images/ie8-panel/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today."></a></div>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!-- <script src="/cdn-cgi/apps/head/3ts2ksMwXvKRuG480KNifJ2_JNM.js"></script> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos-menu.css">
  <style>
    ·#logo {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Page-->
  <div class="page text-center text-md-left">


    <!-- Page Heade

 <header>
     
     <nav>
       
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
       <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT </a></li>
<center>
<img id="logo" style="padding:0;padding-buttom:13px;margin:0;width:8%; height:8%;" src="images/FreshFarms.png">
</center>
     </nav>



  </header>
  <br>
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video id="video" autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="1_1.mp4" type=video/mp4>
    </video>
</div>
    r-->
    <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <video id="video" autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="//clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type=video/mp4>
    </video>
      <!-- Page Header-->
      <!-- RD Navbar-->

      <div class="rd-navbar-brand">
        <a class="brand-name" href="index.html"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/195612/barbarian.png" width="150" alt="Logo Fresh Farms"></a>
      </div>


      <header>

        <nav>

          <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
          <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
          <li style="display:inline-block;float:left; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
          <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
          <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
          <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT</a></li>
          <li style="display:inline-block; float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="#">PRODUCT </a></li>
        </nav>



      </header>
    </div>
    </header>
  </div>
```